# task schedular for python file (.py)

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to schedule a task in task scheduler I have created a batch file as below

```
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" 
 "C:\helloo\mail.py" 
 pause
```

the above is the content of my batch file. When I run the batch file I am able to get the output. I am not facing any issue with the code which I am executing. But with task scheduler I am following the below steps

```
1.open task scheduler 
 2.create task -- provided the name of the task and description 
clicked on run whether the user is logged in or not and run with highest privileges 
3.in triggers -->new --> onetime --ok 
 4.Action --> new--> action :start a program -- 
program script: where I kept my batch file.
5.cliked on finish 
6. I am able to find the task in task scheduler but it is not showing as running
```

I need assistance in Actions tab

Comment: can anyone please help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have added the Action tab as below

```
1.in program i have mentioned PowerShell.exe
2. in next space i have mentioned -f " the file which you want to execute click on the file and click shift+right click and select copy as path "
```

Comment: I need the same for python file